# Is "conditional independence" of $\sigma$-algebras implied by "set-wise conditional independence" of $\sigma$-algebras?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, let $\mathcal{G}_1,\mathcal{G}_2,\mathcal{H}$ be sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal{F}$, and suppose that for all $G_1 \in \mathcal{G}_1$, $G_2 \in \mathcal{G}_2$ and $H \in \mathcal{H}$ with $\mathbb{P}(H)>0$, $G_1$ and $G_2$ are conditionally independent given $H$. Does it follow that
> >     $$ \mathbb{P}(G_1 \cap G_2 | \mathcal{H}) \overset{\mathbb{P}\textrm{-a.s.}}{=} \mathbb{P}(G_1|\mathcal{H})\mathbb{P}(G_2|\mathcal{H}) $$
> >     for all $G_1 \in \mathcal{G}_1$ and $G_2 \in \mathcal{G}_2$?

*More extenstive discussion of the problem, and my attempts so far, now follows.*

---

---

Fix a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and sub-$\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{G}_1,\mathcal{G}_2,\mathcal{H}$ of $\mathcal{F}$.

**Definition of conditional independence:**

> > We say that *$\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are **conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent** given $\mathcal{H}$* if the following equivalent statements [1, Sec. 3.2, p131] hold:
> >
> > - for all $G_1 \in \mathcal{G}_1$ and $G_2 \in \mathcal{G}_2$, $\ \mathbb{P}(G_1 \cap G_2 | \mathcal{H}) \overset{\mathbb{P}\textrm{-a.s.}}{=} \mathbb{P}(G_1|\mathcal{H})\mathbb{P}(G_2|\mathcal{H}) \,$;
> > - for all $G_1 \in \mathcal{G}_1$, there is an $\mathcal{H}$-measurable version of $\mathbb{P}(G_1|\sigma(\mathcal{G}_2 \cup \mathcal{H}))$;
> > - for all $G_2 \in \mathcal{G}_2$, there is an $\mathcal{H}$-measurable version of $\mathbb{P}(G_2|\sigma(\mathcal{G}_1 \cup \mathcal{H}))$.
> >
> > ---
> >
> > [1] M. M. Rao, *Probability Theory with Applications*, Academic Press, Inc., 1984.

The heuristic interpretation is: "If I have the knowledge of $\mathcal{H}$, the whole of $\mathcal{H}$ and nothing but $\mathcal{H}$, then from this standpoint $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are independent."

Note that conditional independence of $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ given $\mathcal{H}$ neither implies nor is implied by independence of $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$.

---

**Definition of "set-wise conditional independence":**

> > I will say that *$\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are **set-wise conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent** given $\mathcal{H}$* if
> >     $$ \hspace{23mm} \mathbb{P}(G_1 \cap H)\mathbb{P}(G_2 \cap H) \ = \ \mathbb{P}(G_1 \cap G_2 \cap H)\mathbb{P}(H) \hspace{20mm} (\ast) $$
> >     for all $G_1 \in \mathcal{G}_1$, $G_2 \in \mathcal{G}_2$ and $H \in \mathcal{H}$.

For any $E \in \mathcal{F}$ with $\mathbb{P}(E)>0$, define the probability measure $\mathbb{P}_E$ by $\mathbb{P}_E(A)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap E)}{\mathbb{P}(E)}$. Then the formula $(\ast)$ is equivalent to the statement, "if $\mathbb{P}(H)>0$ then $G_1$ and $G_2$ are $\mathbb{P}_H$-independent".

Note that if $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are set-wise conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent given $\mathcal{H}$, then in particular $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are $\mathbb{P}$-independent. The heuristic interpretation of set-wise conditional independence is *meant* to be: "$\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are independent, and no amount of knowledge from $\mathcal{H}$ will change this".

**Remark.** If $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are set-wise conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent given $\mathcal{H}$, then for any $H_0 \in \mathcal{H}$ with $\mathbb{P}(H_0)>0$, $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are set-wise conditionally $\mathbb{P}_{H_0}$-independent given $\mathcal{H}$.

---

**THE QUESTION.**

Given what the intuition behind set-wise conditional independence is meant to be, a natural question is:

> > Are the following statements equivalent?
> >
> > - $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are set-wise conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent given $\mathcal{H}$.
> > - For every sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ of $\mathcal{H}$, $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent given $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$.

This question easily simplifies to:

> > Does set-wise conditional independence given $\mathcal{H}$ imply conditional independence given $\mathcal{H}$?

[To see this: If set-wise conditional independence given $\mathcal{H}$ is equivalent to conditional independence under every sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{H}$, then in particular set-wise conditional independence given $\mathcal{H}$ implies conditional independence given $\mathcal{H}$. Conversely, suppose set-wise conditional independence implies conditional independence. In the one direction, obviously set-wise conditional independence given $\mathcal{H}$ implies set-wise conditional independence -- and hence conditional independence -- given every sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{H}$. In the other direction, set-wise conditional independence given $\mathcal{H}$ is verified set-wise as a consequence of conditional independence given $\sigma(\{H\})$ for each $H \in \mathcal{H}$.]

**Intuitively, I think the answer ought to be *yes*. And yet, I'm having trouble proving it.**

(One special case where the answer should clearly be *yes* is when $\mathcal{H}$ has a generator consisting of countably many mutually disjoint sets; but I am interested in the general case.)

---

**A further characterisation of the question:**

Let us say that *$\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ have uncorrelated conditional probabilities under $\mathbb{P}$ given $\mathcal{H}$* if for all $G_1 \in \mathcal{G}_1$ and $G_2 \in \mathcal{G}_2$ the random variables $\mathbb{P}(G_1|\mathcal{H})$ and $\mathbb{P}(G_2|\mathcal{H})$ are uncorrelated random variables over $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$.

Then yet another equivalent formulation of the question (as a *general question* about general probability spaces and sub-$\sigma$-algebras) turns out to be the following:

> > Does set-wise conditional independence given $\mathcal{H}$ imply uncorrelated conditional probabilities given $\mathcal{H}$?

To see the equivalence, we give the following two lemmas:

**Lemma 1.** *If $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent given $\mathcal{H}$, then the following statements are equivalent:*

- *$\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are $\mathbb{P}$-independent;*
- *$\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ have uncorrelated conditional probabilities under $\mathbb{P}$ given $\mathcal{H}$*.

**Lemma 2.** *If $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are set-wise conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent given $\mathcal{H}$, then the following statements are equivalent:*

- *$\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent given $\mathcal{H}$;*
- *for every $H \in \mathcal{H}$ with $\mathbb{P}(H)>0$, $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ have uncorrelated conditional probabilities under $\mathbb{P}_H$ given $\mathcal{H}$.*

If set-wise conditional independence implies conditional independence, then by Lemma 1, set-wise conditional independence also implies uncorrelated conditional probabilities. And if set-wise conditional independence implies uncorrelated conditional probabilities, then applying this to $\mathbb{P}_H$ for all $H \in \mathcal{H}$ with $\mathbb{P}(H)>0$ (which we can do by virtue of the Remark further above), we have by Lemma 2 that set-wise conditional independence implies conditional independence.

**Proof of Lemma 1.** Assume $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent given $\mathcal{H}$. For any $G_1 \in \mathcal{G}_1$ and $G_2 \in \mathcal{G}_2$, we have
$$ \mathbb{P}(G_1)\mathbb{P}(G_2) \ = \ \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}[\mathbb{P}(G_1|\mathcal{H})]\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}[\mathbb{P}(G_2|\mathcal{H})] $$
and
$$ \mathbb{P}(G_1 \cap G_2) \ = \ \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}[\mathbb{P}(G_1|\mathcal{H})\mathbb{P}(G_2|\mathcal{H})]. $$

**Proof of Lemma 2.** Assume $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are set-wise conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent given $\mathcal{H}$. Clearly the following statements are equivalent:

- $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent given $\mathcal{H}$;
- for every $H \in \mathcal{H}$ with $\mathbb{P}(H)>0$,
  $$ \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(H)}\int_H \mathbb{P}(G_1 \cap G_2|\mathcal{H}) \, d\mathbb{P} \ = \ \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(H)}\int_H \mathbb{P}(G_1|\mathcal{H})\mathbb{P}(G_2|\mathcal{H}) \, d\mathbb{P}. $$

Now in this last equality,
$$ \mathrm{RHS} \ = \ \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}_H\!}[\mathbb{P}_H(G_1|\mathcal{H})\mathbb{P}_H(G_2|\mathcal{H})] $$
and using set-wise conditional independence,
$$ \mathrm{LHS} \ = \ \mathbb{P}_H(G_1 \cap G_2) \ = \ \mathbb{P}_H(G_1)\mathbb{P}_H(G_2) \ = \ \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}_H\!}[\mathbb{P}_H(G_1|\mathcal{H})]\,\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}_H\!}[\mathbb{P}_H(G_2|\mathcal{H})]. $$

---

**Further thoughts towards solving the problem (and more generally towards understanding set-wise conditional independence).**

**1.** One question we could ask is whether, in general, conditional probabilities of independent events are uncorrelated, or perhaps even independent, random variables. The answer is **no**.

(The independence question has actually already been addressed in Math.SE, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659917).)

Take the probability space $\{1,2\} \times \{1,2\}$ with the uniform distribution. The events $A:=\{\textrm{1st coordinate is }1\}$ and $B:=\{\textrm{2nd coordinate is }1\}$ are obviously independent; but letting $C=\{(1,1)\}$, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Prob}(A|C) = \mathrm{Prob}(B|C) &= 1 \\
\mathrm{Prob}(A|C^c) = \mathrm{Prob}(B|C^c) &= \tfrac{1}{3}.
\end{align*}

The events $\{\mathrm{Prob}(A|\sigma(\{C\}))=1\}$ and $\{\mathrm{Prob}(B|\sigma(\{C\}))=1\}$ are certainly not independent events, but are in fact the same non-trivial event $C$ itself. Moreover, in this example, the random variables $\mathrm{Prob}(A|\sigma(\{C\}))$ and $\mathrm{Prob}(B|\sigma(\{C\}))$ are strictly positively correlated:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Exp}[\mathrm{Prob}(A|\sigma(\{C\})).\mathrm{Prob}(B|\sigma(\{C\}))] \ &> \ \mathrm{Prob}(C).\mathrm{Prob}(A|C).\mathrm{Prob}(B|C) \\
&= \ \tfrac{1}{4} \ = \ \mathrm{Prob}(A).\mathrm{Prob}(B).
\end{align*}

**2.** We have the following:

**Lemma 3.** *Let $G_1,G_2 \in \mathcal{F}$ be $\mathbb{P}$-independent events. Then the set $\Lambda$ of all $H \in \mathcal{F}$ that are $\mathbb{P}$-independent of $G_1$ and fulfil $(\ast)$ forms a $\lambda$-system on $\Omega$.*

This immediately follows from the following:

**Lemma 4.** *For any $G_1,G_2,H_1,H_2 \in \mathcal{F}$ with $H_1 \subset H_2$, if*

- *at least one of $G_1$ and $G_2$ is both $\mathbb{P}$-independent of $H_1$ and $\mathbb{P}$-independent of $H_2$, and*
- *$(\ast)$ is fulfilled with $H:=H_1$ and with $H:=H_2$*

*then $(\ast)$ is fulfilled with $H:=H_2 \setminus H_1$.*

*Proof.* First note that for any $G_1,G_2,H \in \mathcal{F}$ with $G_1$ and $H$ being $\mathbb{P}$-independent, $(\ast)$ is equivalent to the statement that $G_1$ and $G_2 \cap H$ are $\mathbb{P}$-independent. So now assume the conditions of the Lemma, with $H_1$ and $H_2$ each being $\mathbb{P}$-independent of $G_1$, from which it follows that $H_2 \setminus H_1$ is $\mathbb{P}$-independent of $G_1$. We know that $G_2 \cap H_1$ and $G_2 \cap H_2$ are each $\mathbb{P}$-independent of $G_1$, from which it follows that $G_2 \cap (H_2 \setminus H_1)$ is $\mathbb{P}$-independent of $G_1$. Hence the result.

**3.** Let us now consider a relatively basic case of set-wise conditional independence:

**Proposition 5.** *Let $\mathcal{G}_1,\mathcal{G}_2,\mathcal{G}_3$ be mutually $\mathbb{P}$-independent sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal{F}$.*

- *For any $\,G_1,\tilde{G}_1 \in \mathcal{G}_1$, $\ G_2,\tilde{G}_2 \in \mathcal{G}_2\,$ and $\,\tilde{G}_3 \in \mathcal{G}_3$, $(\ast)$ is fulfilled with $H:=\tilde{G}_1 \cap \tilde{G}_2 \cap \tilde{G}_3$.*
- *Let $\mathcal{H}$ be either $\sigma(\mathcal{G}_1 \cup \mathcal{G}_3)$ or $\sigma(\mathcal{G}_2 \cup \mathcal{G}_3)$. Then $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are set-wise conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent given $\mathcal{H}$, and are also conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent given any sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ of $\mathcal{H}$.*

*Proof.* The first part is a straightforward verification: both sides of the equation $(\ast)$ simplify to
$$ \mathbb{P}(G_1 \cap \tilde{G}_1)\mathbb{P}(G_2 \cap \tilde{G}_2)\mathbb{P}(\tilde{G}_1)\mathbb{P}(\tilde{G}_2)\mathbb{P}(\tilde{G}_3)^2. $$
Now let $\mathcal{H}=\sigma(\mathcal{G}_2 \cup \mathcal{G}_3)$. The set-wise conditional independence follows from the first part of the proposition by Lemma 3 (using the Dynkin $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem). As for the conditional independence given sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ of $\mathcal{H}$: for any $G_1 \in \mathcal{G}_1$ and $G_2 \in \mathcal{G}_2$, since $G_1$ is independent of $\sigma(\{G_2\} \cup \tilde{\mathcal{H}})$ we have
$$ \mathbb{P}(G_1 \cap G_2|\tilde{\mathcal{H}}) \ = \ \mathbb{P}(G_1)\mathbb{P}(G_2|\tilde{\mathcal{H}}) \ = \ \mathbb{P}(G_1|\tilde{\mathcal{H}})\mathbb{P}(G_2|\tilde{\mathcal{H}}). $$

**Definition.** I will say that *$\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are trivially set-wise conditionally $\mathbb{P}$-independent given $\mathcal{H}$* if $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are $\mathbb{P}$-independent and there exists a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}_3$ of $\mathcal{F}$ that is $\mathbb{P}$-independent of $\sigma(\mathcal{G}_1 \cup \mathcal{G}_2)$, such that $\mathcal{H}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of either $\sigma(\mathcal{G}_1 \cup \mathcal{G}_3)$ or $\sigma(\mathcal{G}_2 \cup \mathcal{G}_3)$.

> > So Proposition 5 gives an affirmative answer to my question in the case of "trivial" set-wise conditional independence; but I don't know if it's possible to have "non-trivial" cases of set-wise conditional independence.

Comment: Are you able to prove the reverse implication?

Comment: The reverse implication is trivially false (unless I've misunderstood you): any two $\sigma$-algebras are conditionally independent given $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: I should perhaps have clarified that the "heuristic interpretation" I gave was only meant to be for the "unconventional" concept of set-wise conditional independence, not the "traditional" concept of conditional independence. I will add a "heuristic interpretation" of the latter.

Comment: @JulianNewman how much time have you spent trying to find counter-examples? seems like it might be a good investment at this point..

Comment: Well, the time I spent formulating and investigating what I retrospectively have called the "trivial" case (which was quite a lot of time) can be seen as first steps towards seeing if there is a counterexample; at this point I could spend further time trying to see if "non-trivial" cases exist. But in any case, the **real** difficulty in trying to construct counterexamples is that the statement is true whenever $\mathcal{H}$ is generated by a countable partition.

Comment: So in particular, the "usual source of tractable counterexamples", namely when $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ is a finite or countable discrete space, cannot give counterexamples in this case. In other words, any counterexamples must arise from "uncountable complexity" of interactions of members of $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: @JulianNewman thank you for your helpful comment. in the future, you should tag people (with the @ symbol) so that they are notified of your response. I stumbled upon your response by chance

Comment: @mathworker21 Thank you for the reply and for your suggestion. Did you, by any chance, have any reason/intuition for suspecting that set-wise conditional independence does not always imply conditional independence (apart from my failure thus far to prove what seems like it should have an easy proof if it's true)?

Comment: @JulianNewman if you remove the parentheses, then "no". if you keep the parentheses, then maybe "yes". I'll try to work on the problem soon; it's definitely interesting. I'm just busy right now.

Comment: @mathworker21 Thank you. I wouldn't be surprised if there is some relatively easy proof that I just haven't managed to spot yet.

Comment: This is a wild guess, but: I think if $\mathcal{H}$ is is countably generated, you should be able to use something like the Levy Upwards Theorem.

Comment: I also suspected something along these lines. Of course, it would be ideal if we could prove a positive answer without such an assumption, but maybe it's not true in general. (And maybe it's not true even in the countably generated case.)

Comment: @JulianNewman I'm probably missing something, but pseudocydonia's suggestion seems almost immediate given that you've already observed the claim holds if $\mathcal H$ is generated by a countable partition. Can't we just apply Levy's theorem to $$\mathbb P(G_1 \cap G_2 \mid \mathcal H_n) = \mathbb P(G_1 \mid \mathcal H_n)\mathbb P(G_2 \mid \mathcal H_n),$$ where $\mathcal H_n = \sigma(H_1,...,H_n)$ and $H_1,H_2,...$ generate $\mathcal H$?

Comment: @grndl Yes, I think you're right! So the issue now is just whether the result holds for non-countably-generated $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: In that case, I wonder if we can get the general result by approximating with countably generated subalgebras of $\mathcal H$ using similar martingale arguments.

Comment: @grndl I don't think it can be possible to approximate a general $\sigma$-algebra by countably generated $\sigma$-algebras (e.g. consider an uncountably infinite direct product of probability spaces).

Comment: @grndl But I could believe that (maybe requiring the axiom of choice) it might be possible to approximate an arbitrary $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{H}$ by a union [in the pure set-theoretic sense] $\bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathcal{I}} \mathcal{H}_\alpha$ of countably generated $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{H}_\alpha$ with the property that every $\mathcal{H}$-measurable real-valued function is $\mathcal{H}_\alpha$-measurable for some $\alpha$. (All notions of "measurability" and of "approximation" can be interpreted modulo null sets.) This may be enough to prove the general case.

Comment: @grndl Okay, I realise that this can trivially be done: just take $\mathcal{I}$ to be the set of $\mathcal{H}$-measurable real-valued functions, and let $\mathcal{H}_\alpha=\sigma(\alpha)$. So the proof of the general case is probably easy: Letting $(\mathcal{B}_n)$ be a countable generator of $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$, for each $G_1$ and $G_2$ let $\mathcal{H}_n=\sigma(\mathbb{P}(G_1\cap G_2|\mathcal{H})^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_n) \cup \mathbb{P}(G_1|\mathcal{H})^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_n) \cup \mathbb{P}(G_2|\mathcal{H})^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_n))$.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment wasn't very clear. What I had in mind was the following. Let $\mathscr C$ be the set of countably generated sub-sigma-algebras of $\mathcal H$. Order $\mathscr C$ by subset inclusion so that it's a directed set. I believe we can show that the net $(\mathbb P(G \mid \mathcal C))_{\mathcal C \in \mathscr C}$ converges in $L^1$ to $\mathbb P(G \mid \mathcal H)$ for any $G \in \mathcal F$. Is that enough to conclude?

Comment: @grndl It moreover converges in the discrete topology on $L^1(\mathbb{P})$. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is *yes*.

**Proof.** Suppose $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are set-wise conditionally independent given $\mathcal{H}$. First note that for any finite sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\tilde{H}$ of $\mathcal{H}$, if we let $H_1,\ldots,H_n$ be a partition of $\Omega$ that generates $\tilde{H}$ then for each $i$ with $\mathbb{P}(H_i) > 0$, for each $G_1 \in \mathcal{G}_1$ and $G_2 \in \mathcal{G}_2$ we have
$$ \mathbb{P}(G_1 \cap G_2 | \tilde{H})(\omega) = \mathbb{P}_{H_i}(G_1 \cap G_2) = \mathbb{P}_{H_i}(G_1)\mathbb{P}_{H_i}(G_2) = \mathbb{P}(G_1| \tilde{H})(\omega)\mathbb{P}(G_2 | \tilde{H})(\omega) $$
for $\mathbb{P}$-a.a. $\omega \in H_i$.

Now fix $G_1 \in \mathcal{G}_1$ and $G_2 \in \mathcal{G}_2$, and fix versions of the conditional probabilities $\mathbb{P}(G_1|\mathcal{H})$, $\mathbb{P}(G_2|\mathcal{H})$ and $\mathbb{P}(G_1 \cap G_2|\mathcal{H})$. Let $\{B_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a countable generator of $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$, and for each $n$ let $\mathcal{B}_n=\sigma(B_1,\ldots,B_n)$ and let
$$ \tilde{H}_n \ = \ \sigma(\,\mathbb{P}(G_1|\mathcal{H})^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_n) \,\cup\, \mathbb{P}(G_2|\mathcal{H})^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_n) \,\cup\, \mathbb{P}(G_1 \cap G_2|\mathcal{H})^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_n)\,). $$
Let $\tilde{H}_\infty=\sigma(\tilde{H}_n:n \geq 1) \subset \mathcal{H}$. Note that $\mathbb{P}(G_1|\mathcal{H})$, $\mathbb{P}(G_2|\mathcal{H})$ and $\mathbb{P}(G_1 \cap G_2|\mathcal{H})$ are all $\tilde{H}_\infty$-measurable, and hence are $\mathbb{P}$-almost surely equal to $\mathbb{P}(G_1|\tilde{H}_\infty)$, $\mathbb{P}(G_2|\tilde{H}_\infty)$ and $\mathbb{P}(G_1 \cap G_2|\tilde{H}_\infty)$ respectively. Now for each $n$, since $\tilde{H}_n$ is finite we have that
$$ \mathbb{P}(G_1 \cap G_2 | \tilde{H}_n) \ \overset{\mathbb{P}\textrm{-a.s.}}{=} \ \mathbb{P}(G_1 | \tilde{H}_n)\mathbb{P}(G_2 | \tilde{H}_n). $$
Hence Lévy's upward theorem gives the result with $\tilde{H}_\infty$ in place of $\tilde{H}_n$.

Comment: Many thanks to those who wrote comments that enabled the proof. I'm still quite curious as to whether there exist "non-trivial" cases of set-wise conditional independence.

Comment: Although I doubt I have fully understood your text, I am very impressed by your detailed explanations. :)