# Conditional independence of random variables and $\mathbf{E}[XY]=\mathbf{E}[X]\cdot\mathbf{E}[Y]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, independence

Suppose $X,Y$ are integrable random variables on some probability space $\newcommand{\calF}{\mathscr{F}}\newcommand{\pp}{\mathbb{P}}(\Omega,\calF,\pp)$ and suppose $\newcommand{\calG}{\mathscr{G}}\calG\subset\calF$ is a $\sigma$-subalgebra. Neither of the two following conditions implies the other:

1. $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent w.r.t. $\calG$, i.e. $X\;\underset{\calG}{\perp \!\!\!\!\perp}\;Y$,
2. $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbf{E}}\E[X\mid \calG]\perp \!\!\!\!\perp\E[Y\mid\calG]$.

(recall that conditional independence of random variables means that for all $A\in\sigma(X)$ and all $B\in\sigma(Y)$, $\E[1_A1_B\mid\calG]=\E[1_A\mid\calG]\cdot\E[1_B\mid\calG]$.) Indeed [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3858469/11258) shows that (2) does not imply (1), and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2659917/11258) shows that (1) does not imply (2).

---

My question concerns the analogue of one of a useful properties of independence: whenever $X,Y$ are integrable and independent, their product is automatically integrable and
$$\E[XY]=\E[X]\cdot\E[Y].$$
Let's consider $X$ and $Y$ *nonnegative* (for simplicity) integrable real random variables conditionally independent w.r.t. $\calG$. It's easy to see that $\E[XY\mid\calG]=\E[X\mid\calG]\cdot\E[Y\mid\calG]$.

> **Question.** does it hold that $XY$ integrable and $\E[XY]=\E[X]\cdot\E[Y]$?

---

**EDIT.** I now realize that my question makes no sense: if one takes $\calG=\calF$ then $\E[X\mid\calG]=X$ $\pp$-almost surely (and similarly for $Y$) and there is no reason at all why $XY$ should be integrable. I guess the question then becomes: what makes $\calG_0=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ special among $\sigma$-subalgebras of $\calF$? Is it simply the fact that conditional expectation w.r.t. $\calG_0$ produces (almost surely) constant functions?

---

*Proof of $\,\E[XY\mid\calG]=\E[X\mid\calG]\cdot\E[Y\mid\calG]$.* Let us set
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle X_n & = & \sum_{0\leq k< n2^n}\frac{k}{2^n}1_{A_{k,n}},\quad A_{k,n}=\Big[k2^{-n}\leq X< (k+1)2^{-n}\Big]\\
\displaystyle Y_n & = & \sum_{0\leq k< n2^n}\frac{k}{2^n}1_{B_{k,n}},\quad B_{k,n}=\Big[k2^{-n}\leq Y< (k+1)2^{-n}\Big]
\end{array}\right.$$
Since $X,Y$ are assumed integrable they are almost surely finite and so $0\leq X_n\nearrow X$, $0\leq Y_n\nearrow Y$ as well as $0\leq X_nY_n\nearrow XY$ almost surely. By the conditional monotone convergence theorem we get almost sure convergences
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ccccc}
\displaystyle 0 & \leq & \E[X_n\mid\calG] & \nearrow & \E[X\mid\calG]\\
\displaystyle 0 & \leq & \E[Y_n\mid\calG] & \nearrow & \E[Y\mid\calG]\\
\displaystyle 0 & \leq & \E[X_nY_n\mid\calG] & \nearrow & \E[XY\mid\calG]
\end{array}\right.$$
Now for all $n$,
$$X_nY_n=\sum_{0\leq k < n2^n}\sum_{0\leq l < n2^n}kl 1_{A_{k,n}}1_{B_{l,n}}$$
and so, by conditional independence w.r.t. $\calG$,
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\E[X_nY_n\mid\calG]
& = & \displaystyle\sum_{0\leq k < n2^n}\sum_{0\leq l < n2^n}kl\cdot\E[1_{A_{k,n}}1_{B_{l,n}}\mid\calG]\\
& \overset{\pp\text{-a.s.}}= & \displaystyle\sum_{0\leq k < n2^n}\sum_{0\leq l < n2^n}kl\cdot\E[1_{A_{k,n}}\mid\calG]\cdot\E[1_{B_{l,n}}\mid\calG]\\
& = & \displaystyle \E[X_n\mid\calG]\cdot\E[Y_n\mid\calG]
\end{array}$$
Letting $n\to+\infty$ we get $\E[XY\mid\calG]=\E[X\mid\calG]\cdot\E[Y\mid\calG]~$ $\pp$-almost surely.

Comment: "their product is automatically integrable"... Why is that?

Comment: @d.k.o. Independence is equivalent to the pushforward measure $(X,Y)_*\mathbb{P}$ splitting as $X_*\Bbb{P}\otimes Y_*\Bbb{P}$. You can then apply Fubini's theorem to get the integrability of the product $XY$ and the fact that its expectation is the product of the expectations of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Alternatively I prove it in the proof following my question - consider the case where $\mathscr{G}$ is the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$.

Comment: OK. $X$ and $Y$ are independent...

Answer (score 1):

If $X,Y\in\mathrm L^1(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathbf P)$ are independent w.r.t. $\mathscr G$, then it is true that $XY\in\mathrm L^1(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathbf P(\cdot\mid\mathscr G))$ with $\mathbf E[XY\mid\mathscr G]=\mathbf E[X\mid\mathscr G]\,\mathbf E[Y\mid\mathscr G]$.

---

That this implies $\mathbf E[XY]=\mathbf E[X]\,\mathbf E[Y]$ is not true:

Suppose $X,U$ are independent uniform r.v., and let $Y:=XU$. Given $\mathscr G:=\sigma(X)$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent (because $X$ is “a constant”; we have $$\mathbf E[f(X)g(Y)\mid\mathscr G]=f(X)\int_0^1g(Xu)\,\mathrm du=\mathbf E[f(X)\mid\mathscr G]\,\mathbf E[g(Y)\mid\mathscr G]$$ for any measurable functions $f,g\ge0$.)
Nonetheless, $$\mathbf E[XY]=\mathbf E[X^2]\,\mathbf E[U]=\frac16,$$ while $$\mathbf E[X]\,\mathbf E[Y]=\mathbf E[X]^2\,\mathbf E[U]=\frac18.$$

Comment: Thanks, I like your counter example.